# Sporadic bug with SE question ads

Tags: bug, advertising

[image: screencapture of the behavior]

- Opening the ad on a new tab (Ctrl+Click) doesn't work. It simply appends a query string.
- Clicking on the ad shows the navbar in the gif area.